# Getting meta title and description

Tags: php, html, meta-tags

I am having trouble getting the meta description/title from [this specific site](http://www.thegooddrugsguide.com/lsd/index.htm).

Here is some code:

```
$file = file('http://www.thegooddrugsguide.com/lsd/index.htm');
$file = implode("",$file);
if (preg_match('/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/is',$file,$t)) $title = $t[1];
```

It works with other sites, but not with the site in question. What could be the problem?

Comment: DO. NOT. USE. REGEXES. FOR. PARSING. HTML.

Comment: best is to use DOM api http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: say no to drugs... unless there free

Answer (score 20):

This should work fine:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://example.com');

$title = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
$title = $title[0];

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

foreach ($metas as $meta) {
  if (strtolower($meta->getAttribute('name')) == 'description') {
    $description = $meta->getAttribute('value');
  }
}
```

More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

**Edit**: this shorter version can also work to find the description:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$description = $xpath->query('//meta[@name="description"]/@content');
```

Comment: Hey I am getting this error: `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: Invalid char in CDATA 0x1F in http://www.thegooddrugsguide.com/lsd/index.htm, line: 1`

Comment: Also I have tried example.com and then I get this error: `Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array `

Comment: @johnny just edited adding ->item(0)->nodeValue; instead of [0]. Just tested and it works now

Comment: @Baronth : what are you talking about? I am getting the same error 'Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array', can you please mention the change in seriousdev's answer?

Comment: Someone modified it again(or the modify wasn't approved)... I'll write it here: Instead of `$title = $title[0];` use `$title = $title->item(0)->nodeValue;`

Comment: Note that the Edit contains an error.

`$description = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta[name@="description"]/@content');` 

should read 

`$description = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta[@name="description"]/@content');` 

The `@` should come before the name attribute selector not afterwards.

Comment: you should do
`$description = $meta->getAttribute('content');`
instead of `getAttribute('value')`

Answer (score 3):

```
$url = "http://www.thegooddrugsguide.com/lsd/index.htm";    
$tags = get_meta_tags($url);
$description = $tags["description"];
```