# Facebook-like share a link parsing?

Tags: javascript, parsing, hyperlink, facebook-like, share

How does facebook share a link parsing work?
Given a url, i need to extract title, blurb and thumbnail (if any).

Are there any libraries or widgets that already do this?
(preferably client side javascript)

Answer (score 0):

**You cant do this on client only.**

For the reason see: [Why cant I load an external resource from jQuery load method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292486/why-cant-i-load-an-external-resource-from-jquery-load-method) And the [accepted answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292486/why-cant-i-load-an-external-resource-from-jquery-load-method#1292562) gives you the options.

You will have to do it like this:

1. Create a server script that loads the page. Your javascript code sends a request with the given link to this script.
2. This script may parse the requested page to get the wanted information ([This answer may help you for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113716/help-getting-meta-title-and-description#6113811) and [this one for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130095/most-useful-free-third-party-java-libraries#4149168))
3. Your script may return JSON Data which you can process with javascript in the browser