# how to get title and description of a website using php?

Tags: php, meta-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help getting meta title and description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113716/help-getting-meta-title-and-description)

I've spend a full day on it. Searched on the net. Saw some similar questions on satckoverflow also. but all I got  disappointment.

I want to get some php code by which I can output the title and some 4-5 lines for the description of any website using php.

Comment: What do you mean when you say description?

Comment: This is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113716/help-getting-meta-title-and-description/6113811#6113811

Comment: Define "title" and "description" in this case.  For the `title` element in an HTML page you can just get the page and use a DOM parser to extract that tag.  (If the tag exists on that page, which it might not, and if the tag is defined correctly, which it might not be, and if the page is even HTML, which it might not be, etc.)  But what is a "description"?  Where do you expect to get that?  If it's something in a `meta` tag then expect it to not be there even more often than the `title` tag.

Comment: I guess he meant the meta description. Anyways, is this something you were looking for? : http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-meta-tags.php

Comment: it would have been nice to see what you have tried after spending a full day researching the topic … instead of now asking to give teh codez. That would have allowed us to point out where you might have missed something.

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: sorry for wrong doing... but please help me...

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php

  $url = "http://www.drquincy.com/";

  $fp = fopen($url, 'r');
  $content = "";
  while(!feof($fp)) {
        $buffer = trim(fgets($fp, 4096));
        $content .= $buffer;
  }


  $start = '<title>';
  $end = '</title>';
  preg_match(" / $start( . * )$end / s", $content, $match);
  $title = $match[1];
  $metatagarray = get_meta_tags($url);
  $keywords = $metatagarray["keywords"];
  $description = $metatagarray["description"];
  echo " <div><strong>URL: </strong >$url</div> \n";
  echo " <div><strong>Title: </strong >$title</div> \n";
  echo " <div><strong>Description: </strong >$description</div>\n";
  echo " <div><strong>Keywords: </strong >$keywords</div>\n";
```

Just change the url:)

Comment: it isn't working... don't knw what s wrong??

Comment: Chances are that this wont have the desired result your looking for. It will work, but the title will likely be "Browser Not Supported" or something like that. You'll want to send headers (you can do this with fopen)

Comment: it says: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 't' in C:\wamp\www\1.php on line 27
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0005 373336 {main}( ) ..\1.php:0
2 3.5318 411744 preg_match ( ) ..\1.php:27

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: keywords in C:\wamp\www\1.php on line 30
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0005 373336 {main}( ) ..\1.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: description in C:\wamp\www\1.php on line 31
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0005 373336 {main}( ) ..\1.php:0
URL: http://www.drquincy.com/
Title:
Description:
Keywords:

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to parse a HTML. First, you want the content itself:

```
$res = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
```

That assumes file_get_contents allowed to access uri.
For example, you might utilize a regex:

```
preg_match("~<title>(.*?)</title>~", $res, $match);
$title = $match[1];
```

But it would be better to use a DOM parser. http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php, though that may be problem if the target content is not valid xml.