# Any way to extract title and description from every page on a site?

Tags: php, meta-tags

I have 2 versions of a website:

One that I no longer have ftp/code access to, and a nearly identical one that I do have ftp/code access to but that has been stripped of title and description tags.  Is there a way (PHP or otherwise) to crawl the site I no longer have direct access to, and extract title/description meta tags for all pages?

I want to insert those tags into the new version of the site I do have access to.

Comment: [**StackOverflow**](http://bit.ly/4Agih5) is **NOT !**, a place to ask someone for free `codes`. 
[Such Questions are **Not Good** for this site](http://bit.ly/dcqznq), and will be [**Closed**](http://bit.ly/18T95z1), or [**Deleted**](http://bit.ly/10c3VuR), *Instead* [Learn what type](http://bit.ly/r0ZSEc)  of questions you can or should ask. If you have any question about this, feel free to ask on [Meta](http://bit.ly/SgO5J), Or check the [FAQ](http://bit.ly/18T95z1), page for general information.

Comment: what about downloading the whole site via [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget)?

Comment: I know how to download the whole site...I'm trying to find a way to get a "report" or XML or some such that ONLY has the file name, title and description.  I'm not asking for the code.  I'm asking for any thoughts on how to do it ("is there a way" not "gimme the code to...")

Comment: You could also use PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org) along with CasperJS (http://casperjs.org). Those are headless browsers that allow you to crawl your website fairly easy and extract all the information you want

Comment: you can look into this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/get-title-and-meta-tags-of-external-site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to extract the meta description from a page:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$description = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta[name@="description"]/@content');
```

This is an alternative solution:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://example.com');

$title = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
$title = $title[0];

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

foreach ($metas as $meta) {
  if (strtolower($meta->getAttribute('name')) == 'description') {
    $description = $meta->getAttribute('value');
  }
}
```

Source: [#6113716](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113716/)

Comment: Thanks, this is going to put me in the direction I need.  Hadn't looked at loadHTMLfile before.  Thank you!